# Different spring configuration files roles

Tags: java, xml, spring, hibernate, spring-security

I am developing my Spring-based web application using **Spring Framework** + **Spring Security** + **Hibernate** for data access (ORM) + **Maven** as build manager. All data acces operations must be provided by Hibernate.

My goal is to integrate Spring Security, Spring Framework and Hibernate for work together. I read many corresponding tutorials but what is confusing to me is that there are (in tutorials code) many xml-configuration files that missing in my project. [Here is the structure of my project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XIB8k.png)

As you can see there are only two Spring related xml-files and web.xml - they all been automaticaly generated by Spring when I added Spring Framework and Spring Security support to my project.

But in mentioned tutorials there are also files named "spring-database.xml", "spring-security.xml". The first as I think is to configure Spring toget data from database and the second is just basic Spring Security config. file.

**Questions:**
1) Those two files have not been generated automaticaly, even "spring-security.xml". Is it ok - is it like it must be? Or something wrong with my project settings?

2) If I can name those xml config files as I wish - then how does Spring know about them all and distinguish them? I just have not found anything about config files with such names in official Spring refference docs.

Answering question 2 please give some examples if it is possible.

3) My applicationContext file is empty - is it ok? And what if difference between it and dispatcher-servlet?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) I general you need just one spring configuration file, which is normally placed in `src/main/resources` (or elsewhere on the classpath) and after called `applicationContext.xml` or similar. If you use several Spring modules (such as Spring Data, Spring Security etc) it is common practice to have one separate config file for each module, but its not necessary, you can place all config in the same xml.

2) The naming doesn't matter, Spring looks in the classpath for the files: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/145545/where-to-put-spring-configuration-file

3) Normally the applicationContext.xml contains the definition of your beans and packages to scan for annotation and should be placed in `src/main/resources`. I guess dispatcher-servlet.xml is for the URI/servlet mapping (spring mvc)

Answer (score 0):

There is no problem with your project structure. It is not mandatory to have the file names as you have in your project. If you want to have your own names for the xml files you have to mention the names of the xmls in the  in web.xml. See below

```
 <context-param>
   <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
   <param-value>
    /WEB-INF/dispatcher-servlet.xml
    /WEB-INF/spring-security.xml
  </param-value>
 </context-param>
```

Coming to the third question. applicationContext.xml should not be empty. You need to specify the beans of your application (services, dao, etc..) in applicationContext.xml. In dispatcher-servlet.xml you need specify beans (handler mappings, controllers, view resolvers etc..) related to spring mvc.

Comment: But in many tutorials applicationContext is not described at all i.e. it is must be empty or just missing. Why it is possible?